# javascript function to pull html div into master.html div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, external

Got a bit of a problem... basically using this statement in html with a ul menu to activate it.....

```
<div id="subnav" >
        <ul>
            <li id="subone"><a href="#">Definitions</a></li>

        </ul>
</div>

   </div>

   <script src="jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
 $("#subnav ul li a") .click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    $('#content2').load($(this).attr('abc.html') + ' #content2');
    });
  });
   </script>



  <div id="content2">

  </div>
```

......... This does nothing and can't seem to work out why....Can someone please tell me where I am wrong here.  BTW the abc.html page simply has ....

```
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="whatis.css" />
 </head>
  <body>
  <div id="content2"><p>this is a test </p></div>
   <div id="content3"><p>Here comes some content </p></div>
   </body>
  </html>
```

any ideas people ??

cheers,
Greg.

Comment: elaborate, what you want this code to perform and provide jsfiddle link, if possible.

Comment: just to answer Neo I am looking to get a div called content2 from the html file abc.html passed and placed inside master.html in the div also called content2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#content2').load('abc.html #content2');
```

---

`.attr('abc.html')` attempts to return the value of the attribute `abc.html`... so that would work if your `a` looked like this:

```
<a abc.html="something">Definitions</a>
```

(though that wouldn't be a valid attribute)

---

Now if your `a` looked like this:

```
<a href="abc.html">Definitions</a>
```

You could do this:

```
$("#subnav ul li a") .click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    $('#content2').load($(this).attr('href') + ' #content2');
});
```

Comment: ONE PROBLEM !  ----- I have multiple menu items and don't want to do the javascript statement for every single item.... is it possible to have one statement for each menu item?

Comment: any takers for using it for multiple menu items with different divs ??

Comment: Sure, you can do that. You'd have to add some indicator to the markup of your `<a>` elements. You could use a `data-` attribute for example.